# Convert case class with Options to case class without Options

Tags: scala

Having case class with nested Options how do I convert it to its twin case class with no Options by extracting `Some`’s and replacing `None`’s by default values.

Let's say we have:

```
case class UserPreferencesOpt(animals: Option[AnimalPreferencesOpt])
case class AnimalPreferencesOpt(dogs: Option[String], cats: Option[String])

case class UserPreferences(animals: AnimalPreferences)
object UserPreferences {
    def getDefault: UserPreferences(AnimalPreferences("bark", "meow")
}
case class AnimalPreferences(dogs: String, cats: String)
```

So basically, I’d like to convert:

`UserPreferencesOpt(Some(AnimalPreferencesOpt(Some("Dogs are cool!"), None)))`

into:

`UserPreferences(AnimalPreferences("Dogs are cool!", "meow")`

by extracting Options when present and replacing absent with default value.

It can be done by pattern matching and checking value by value, but this is just an example. Obviously, in many cases, there will be much more nested preferences in domain logic and I wonder if it’s possible to convert it without adding extra matches and cases when new preferences are added (eg. `WeatherPreferences` or even something inside UserPreferences).

Having heard of some advanced Scala stuff like Shapeless or macros I think somebody might recommend it, but is there a way to achieve it in *idiomatic, functional, Scala-ish* way?

Comment: I think you should rethink your domain modelling. It seems weird to have a case class, and another case class opt with opt fields, and yet more nested opt case classes

Comment: The one with Options I'd like to use as handling user input in API endpoint, Options serves as user may want to PATCH only some preferences. The class with no Optional is internal modal of domain logic and I care to have all fields stored in JSON in DB. Edit: Could you share some thoughts how can it be better done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify defaults in `apply` in companion object for target case classes. E.g.:

```
case class UserPreferencesOpt(animals: Option[AnimalPreferencesOpt] = None)
case class AnimalPreferencesOpt(dogs: Option[String] = None, cats: Option[String] = None)

case class UserPreferences(animals: AnimalPreferences)
object UserPreferences {
  def apply(o: UserPreferencesOpt): UserPreferences = {
    UserPreferences(
      AnimalPreferences(
        o.animals.getOrElse(AnimalPreferencesOpt())
      ))
  }
}
case class AnimalPreferences(dogs: String, cats: String)

object AnimalPreferences {
  def apply(opt: AnimalPreferencesOpt): AnimalPreferences = {
    AnimalPreferences(
      opt.dogs.getOrElse("bark"),
      opt.cats.getOrElse("meow")
    )
  }
}
```

But I agree with @pedrorijo91 that model looks weird..

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If you also think that this model looks weird, how should I model and handle API entities from user (eg. changing 2 out of 3 preferences)? This case class with options is convertible to JSON in my model and since that, event empty JSON is still valid. However though, the class with no options represent domain model (eg. with boolean preferences I don't distinguish None and Some(false), there are only true and false, and if something is not specified, I am adding default value to database

Comment: I would say you need to distinguish Model classes and UI classes. And move your defaults as close to UI as possible. E.g. if you use play-json you can pre-define your reader with defaults (using `Reads.pure`) and convert directly to model classes which you operates internally, or first into intermediate UI-related case classes (because, for example if some non-trivial additional validation required) which could be converted in-place into model classes. For other  json-libs think defaults should be also available..

Answer (score 1):

If the default are static, then the simpler solution is to fill it at the instance construction, and not having class with Options.

For your example, that would be:

```
case class UserPreferences(animals: AnimalPreferences)
case class AnimalPreferences(dogs: String, cats: String)

object UserPreferences {
  def apply(dogOpt: Option[String], catOpt: Option[String]): UserPreferences = {
    val dog = dogOpt.getOrElse("bark")
    val cat = catOpt.getOrElse("meow")
    UserPreferences(AnimalPreferences(dog, cat))
  }
}

// then you can create, eg:
UserPreferences(None, None)
UserPreferences("Grrr", None)
UserPreferences("Dogs are cool!", "meow")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another *scala-ish* way to solve this problem is using `implicit conversions`. You have to define `implicit methods` that convert toConvert class to required class e.g. `UserPreferenceOpt` to `UserPreference` in their respective companion classes.

```
  case class UserPreferencesOpt(animals: Option[AnimalPreferencesOpt])
  case class AnimalPreferencesOpt(dogs: Option[String], cats: Option[String])

  case class UserPreferences(animals: AnimalPreferences)
  case class AnimalPreferences(dogs: String, cats: String)

  //Note that, I have used `null` value in case of `None` found in Opt class. Instead of `null`, you can provide default value with some logic here.
  object UserPreferencesOpt {
    implicit def optToUserPref(userPref: UserPreferencesOpt): UserPreferences = UserPreferences(userPref.animals.getOrElse(null))
  }
  object AnimalPreferencesOpt {
    implicit def optToAnimalPref(animalPref: AnimalPreferencesOpt): AnimalPreferences = AnimalPreferences(animalPref.dogs.getOrElse(null), animalPref.cats.getOrElse(null))
  }
  val userPrefOpt:UserPreferencesOpt = UserPreferencesOpt(Some(AnimalPreferencesOpt(Some("Dogs are cool!"), None)))
  val userPref: UserPreferences = userPrefOpt
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a [library](https://github.com/kailuowang/henkan) supports this feature, like this:

```
import cats.data.Validated
import cats.implicits._
import henkan.optional.all._

case class Message(a: Option[String], b: Option[Int])
case class Domain(a: String, b: Int)

validate(Message(Some("a"), Some(2))).to[Domain]
// res0: henkan.optional.ValidateFromOptional.Result[Domain] = Valid(Domain(a,2))

validate(Message(Some("a"), None)).to[Domain]
// res1: henkan.optional.ValidateFromOptional.Result[Domain] = Invalid(NonEmptyList(RequiredFieldMissing(b)))
```